# How do I make a textarea dynamically change?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, textarea

I am working on a hacking simulation game, and there are fake log files that every user would have. My question is, how would I dynamically update an HTML textarea to display them? I was going to try mySQL, but I don't think it would work, because the "logs" are fairly large and might go over the row size limit. Would javascript be an option? Thank you.

Comment: MySQL is server side, Javascript and textarea's are client side so mysql wouldnt really apply here, You could do it dynamically you could javascript [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) which could then resize the textarea when the data changes.

Comment: This question is pretty broad. Yes it would be an option, but you've not clearly detailed what you're trying to do and haven't provided any information on what you may have already tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this?

`document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = '';`

```
<textarea id="myTextarea">
Text that changes
</textarea>
```

Comment: Not yet, I don't know much JS, but I know a lot of php. I'll try it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: `$("#myTextarea").val('Text that changes')` for jquery

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at a declarative 2-way binding framework like [Rivets](http://www.rivetsjs.com/). Frameworks like this allow you to annotate your HTML with attributes that "bind" them to your data such that when you update your data your HTML will automatically change. There are adapters that let you use this with Backbone and other frameworks if you choose.

This is the same concept behind things like [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), [Angular](http://angularjs.org/) and [D3](http://d3js.org/).

Here is an example from Rivets

```
<section id="auction">
  <h1>{ action.title }</h1>
  <img rv-src="action.image.url">

  <aside rv-show='auction.remaining | lt 120'>
    <h4>Hurry up!<h4>
    <p>This auction is ending in { auction.remaining | time }.</p>
  </aside>

  <button rv-on-click="controller.bid">Place a bid</button>
</section>
```

The JavaScript to actually Bind

```
rivets.bind($('#auction'), {
  auction: auctionModel,
  controller: controllerObject
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** - for pure javascript with no jQuery

HTML

```
<textarea id="text" rows="4" cols="50">
    At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all
    web development technologies. Right now, the rows is set to 4 and you will be able to 
    change     them to either 2 or 7 by pressing the appropriate buttons
</textarea>
<br />
<button id="change2" onClick="changeRows2()" type="button">Change Rows to 2</button>
<button id="change7" onClick="changeRows7()" type="button">Change Rows to 7</button>
```

JavaScript

```
changeRows2 = function(){
    document.getElementById('text').rows = 2;
}

changeRows7 = function(){
    document.getElementById('text').rows = 7;
}
```

Updated the original fiddle to use only javascript -
[jsfiddle showing how to do it](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/dLV7z/1/)

**Original answer**

You would have to use javascript.

Html

```
<textarea id="text" rows="4" cols="50">
This is going to be the placeholder text that you will change dynamically.  I set the rows to 4 and then you can change them to 2 or 7.  Hope this helps.
</textarea>
<br />
<button id="change2" type="button">Change to 2</button>

<button id="change7" type="button">Change to 7</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('#change2').on('click', function(){
        $('#text').attr('rows', 2);
    });

    $('#change7').on('click', function(){
        $('#text').attr('rows', 7);
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle showing how to do it.

[Dynamically change rows](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/dLV7z/)

I used buttons to manipulate the textarea in this example but you could use the same line of code in the success callback of an ajax call.

Comment: This is jQuery, not javascript. But with jQuery is working. It's not clear if he was looking just for Javascript or also jQuery. But it's tagged with javascript and not jQuery

Comment: I thought about that.  I just updated my answer to show a pure javascript way of doing what I "think" the OP wanted.